# Is it possible to read from a file that is already open in another process for writing in windows?

Tags: windows

There is a process that writes data into a file as it executes.

Is it possible to read data from this file while still data is being written to it?

Answer (score 0):

I've used notepad++ https://notepad-plus-plus.org/ to read log files that are being written to in Windows 7 without any issues, but it depends--Check wikipedia for more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking